# Ruby JSON tree to SVG

Tags: ruby, json, svg, tree

I have this project where I have to parse a JSON tree and generate an SVG image and this is my code so far:

```
require 'json'


def treeNode(x, y, str)
    textX = x - 15
    textY = y + 5
    '<circle cx = "'+x.to_s+'" cy = "'+y.to_s+'" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>'+"\n"+
    '<text x = "'+textX.to_s+'" y = "'+textY.to_s+'" fill = "black">'+str.to_s+'</text> '+"\n"
end

def makeTree(x, y, hash, file)

 xDistance = 140
 yDistance = 100

 hash.each do |key, value| 
    if value.kind_of?(String)
      file << treeNode(x, y, value)
    elsif value.kind_of?(Hash)
      file << makeTree(x, y, value, file)
    elsif value.kind_of?(Array)
      value.each do |e|
        file << makeTree(x, y, e, file)
        x += xDistance
      end
    end
    y += yDistance
  end
end

jsonFile = ARGV[0]
data = Hash.new()
file = File.read(jsonFile)
data = JSON.parse(file)

File.open('B_14_Ivo_Gerginov.svg', 'w') do |svg|
  svg << '<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10000" height="10000">' + "\n"
  makeTree(60, 60, data, svg)
  svg << '</svg>'
end
```

My problem is that the branches kind of overlap, and their positioning is a little screwy. I'm supposed to do it recursively, so it has to be fixed in the `makeTree()` method. Can anyone give me an idea?

Input: `ruby tree.rb test.json`

the test JSON file(disclaimer, i didn't write the JSON file, it was given to me for the task):

```
{
  "node_name" : "TUES",
  "children" : [
    { "node_name": "11a",
      "children" : [
                        {"node_name": "Kiril"},
                        {"node_name": "Mitov"}  
      ]},
    { "node_name": "11b",
      "children" : [
                        {"node_name": "Nenko"},
                        {"node_name": "Tabakov"},
                        {"node_name": "Bojidar"}
      ]}
  ]
}
```

Output: a .svg file containing this:

```
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10000" height="10000">
<circle cx = "60" cy = "60" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "45" y = "65" fill = "black">TUES</text> 
<circle cx = "60" cy = "160" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "45" y = "165" fill = "black">11a</text> 
<circle cx = "60" cy = "260" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "45" y = "265" fill = "black">Kiril</text> 
{"node_name"=>"Kiril"}<circle cx = "200" cy = "260" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "185" y = "265" fill = "black">Mitov</text> 
{"node_name"=>"Mitov"}{"node_name"=>"11a", "children"=>[{"node_name"=>"Kiril"}, {"node_name"=>"Mitov"}]}<circle cx = "200" cy = "160" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "185" y = "165" fill = "black">11b</text> 
<circle cx = "200" cy = "260" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "185" y = "265" fill = "black">Nenko</text> 
{"node_name"=>"Nenko"}<circle cx = "340" cy = "260" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "325" y = "265" fill = "black">Tabakov</text> 
{"node_name"=>"Tabakov"}<circle cx = "480" cy = "260" r = "40" stroke = "black" stroke-width = "2" fill = "none"/>
<text x = "465" y = "265" fill = "black">Bojidar</text> 
{"node_name"=>"Bojidar"}{"node_name"=>"11b", "children"=>[{"node_name"=>"Nenko"}, {"node_name"=>"Tabakov"}, {"node_name"=>"Bojidar"}]}</svg>
```

It's supposed to look like a tree, but I haven't done the lines yet, and the second branch is overlapping the first one.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of your input data, the output you're getting and the output you expect.